CPF5149 with a setll *loval
I get the following error when I try to setll s a logical file
he is my code :
H OPTION(*NODEBUGIO:*SRCSTMT) dATFMT(*DMY)                          
FOPRBAS00  IF   E             DISK    extfile('M3FDBDEV/OPRBAS')    
f                                     rename(OPRBAS:OPRBAS_IN)      
f                                     prefix(in_)                   
FOPRBAS    O    E             DISK    extfile('M3FARDEV/OPRBAS')    
f                                     rename(OPRBAS:OPRBAS_out)     
f                                     prefix(out_)                  
FOPRBAS20  IF   E           k DISK    rename(OPRBAS:OPRBAS_20)      
******************************************************************  
Ditno             S             15                                  
Dcono             S              3P 0                               
Dprrf             S              2                                  
Dfvdt             S              8P 0                               
******************************************************************  
                                                    
   SETLL *loval OPRBAS_IN ;   
   Read OPRBAS_IN ;                                                 
   Dow not %eof();                                                  
   ......
    Read OPRBAS_IN ;
    enddo;
   .....

Could you help me please?
Thank you

You should be using *START instead of *LOVAL to position to the first record.
See the SETLL operation code documentation for more information.

I get this error *RNF5319 while compiling with *start

Using *START requires the specification of the file name, not record name...
So
SETLL *start OPRBAS00;

Modern RPG best practice is to "read a file, write a record".
This assumes you aren't dealing with a mult-format logical.
